# Python regex: match only if the next group's value is not an empty string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

If I have a regular expression like this: `r'abc(.*?)'`, how to match `'abc'` only if the following group's value is not an empty string?

Comment: Easy, you use a lookahead `abc(?=.)`. You basically assert that there's at least one character ahead. Remember that `.` doesn't match a newline by default. So you might use `[\s\S]` or just enable the `s` modifier.

Comment: What if I want to find the value of the characters following `"abc"`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use :

```
r = re.compile(r'abc(.+)')
match = r.match('abc123')
value = r.group(1)
```

This would match only strings with characters following abc and value (e.g 123) would be in .group(1) of match object.

Comment: That's not what I actually want, HamZa's answer was right but I wanted to find the value of `(?=.)` as if it's a group

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand what you wanted.

Comment: @whiletrue A positive lookahead is meant to assert that there's something ahead *without* saving it. So if you want to *save* it and *retrieve* its value then you might as well use a capturing group `abc(.+)`. The problem here is that group 0 will contain everything. So you might use a lookahead with a capturing group `abc(?=(.+))` or use two groups `(abc)(.+)`. Hope this clears the misunderstanding...

Answer (score 0):

```
abc(.+)
```

Try this.This will give `abc` followed by non empty group.